# Access to only few fields of a content type for specific user

Tags: entities, nodes

I am using drupal 6. I have created one content type 'video' in which I have many fields like url,language,locations etc. I have created 1 role, Now I just want to give permissions to that particular role so that he can only add fields like url,locations. He shouldn't be able to use other fields.
Any Suggestion,

Answer (score 4):

[Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) will let you assign different permissions to a field based on role.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is asking how to limit the _addition_ of certain types of field, not how to set CRUD permissions for existing fields

Comment: I read it as adding content to those fields. I guess we'll find out!

Comment: Now that you mention it yeah, it's pretty ambiguous!